# Removing location without removing the rest of the path

Tags: nginx

According to many old posts here and in other places on the internet, the following nginx configuration should proxy `http://nginx-service/foo/bar` to `http://web.default.svc.cluster.local:8080/bar`.

In other words, it should strip the `/foo` part in the path (the location matched) while appending the rest (`/bar`) when proxying it on.

That is not what I observe in practice; the full path is removed and `/` is proxied on.

How could I proxy this to the upstream service while keeping `/bar`?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add any config in your question but any of the following should work:

```
location /foo/ {
  proxy_pass http://web.default.svc.cluster.local:8080/;
}
```

or

```
location /foo/bar {
  proxy_pass http://web.default.svc.cluster.local:8080/bar;
}
```